# For A,B subsets of a Normed Vector Space, A closed, B Compact, Show A - B Is Closed

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

***Statement of the problem:***

Let $E$ be a Normed Vector Space over the real numbers. Let $A, B$ be subsets of $E$ such that:

$A$ and $B$ are non-empty, $A \cap B = \emptyset $. Assume $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact. Define the set $C := A - B = \cup_{b \in B} (A - b)$. Here, $A - b = \{ a - b : a \in A \}$. i.e. a translation of the set $A$ in the direction of $-b$.

Prove that C is closed.

I am sure that $B$ being compact is key here, and suspect I should consider finite covers in some way, but I cannot figure out why $A - S$ should be closed for any potentially infinite set $S$... Could someone please offer me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$? Otherwise $A - B$ is just $A$.

Comment: No I did not. Here, $A - b = \{ a - b : a \in A \}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $z$ is a point from the boundary of
$A-B$. There exists a sequence $z_n\in A-B$
for which $z_n\to z$. Here, $z_n=a_n-b_n$,
and $a_n\in A, b_n\in B$. But $A$ is a compact set, so there exists a convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}\to a\in A$.
As a hint, try to prove that $z$ also belongs to $A-B$.